# Connecting to Wifi with Specific SSID

Tags: java, android, wifi, ssid

I am trying to let my app connect to WIFI  with a specific SSID which has certain speed but to do so i have to disconnect from the current network and connect to the new SSID but this is very difficult because it is always going to the previous network. i tried this code

```
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
String networkSSID="MY_SSID";
String networkPass="MY_PASS";
int netid;
WifiManager wifiManager;
WifiConfiguration conf;
wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
conf=new WifiConfiguration();
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
netid = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
boolean es=wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
conf.priority=40;
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netid, true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Comment: "i tried this code" and...?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca and "it is always going to the previous network.", I guess

Comment: Which classes Are you using? Wäre is WifiManager from?